# Counting types of relationships in a table

Tags: sql

How can I count the number of many to many relationships in a table?  If I have a table with of individuals with two organization codes (say, 'unit' and 'code'), how could I produce a listing of how many units are in a many-to-many relationship with codes?

Our goal is to see how substitutable they are.

Answer (score 0):

Get the distict count of the units to see how many units have a relation:

```
select count(distinct unit) from individuals
```

Comment: Thanks; I've already done that for both fields, and also produced a list of unique Unit*Code combinations (and counts of how many times they occurred in the survey.